# AJAX Predictive Search

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have a basic HTML form that I want to fill in with the names of the US states. I have all of 50 of them (Alabama to Wyoming) stored in the following format:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<states xml:lang="EN">
<item>
<label>Alabama</label>
<value>AL</value>
</item>
<item>
<label>Alaska</label>
<value>AK</value>
</item>
...
```

I wrote some AJAX for this:

```
function ajaxFunction(str) {
  if (str.length==0) { 
    document.getElementById("search").innerHTML="";
    document.getElementById("search").style.border="0px";
    return;
  }
  var ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
  ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (ajaxRequest.readyState==4 && ajaxRequest.status==200) {
      document.getElementById("search").innerHTML=ajaxRequest.responseText;
      document.getElementById("search").style.border="1px solid #A5ACB2";
    }
  }
  ajaxRequest.open("GET","USA_States.xml",true);
  ajaxRequest.send();
}
```

HTML:

```
<form id = "form1">
  <input onkeyup="ajaxFunction(this.value);" type = "text" size = "30" id = "text1" autocomplete="off"/>
  <div id = "search">
```

And it still does not work. Suggestions? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what doesn't work? do you get an error? does a function not get called? what happens?

Comment: Without even looking ar your Javascript I would say start by fixing your HTML if that is what it looks like. Is `<div id="search">` inside of `<form id="form1">`? And why are you not closing any of your tags (e.g. `<div id="search">` needs a `</div>`).

Comment: Nothing appears in the textbox.

Comment: Not really an answer to your question, but it's pretty unnecessary to make an HTTP request for every keypress when your search target is such a well-defined static list of just 50 items. I'd just hardcode the list of states in JS and handle the auto-fill completely on the client side.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I just forgot to attach the whole code, in my file all the tags are actually closed.

Comment: I would concur with @AlexHowansky - even if you don't hard code it, a single ajax call to get 50 items would not be large enough to warrant 'searching' the items on _every_ key press

Comment: is the response text html?

Comment: Okay, because the example you gave makes me assume it's XML. If it's html, then it should work. You also need to make sure the search and its contents are properly sized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be looking for this.Replace your javascript code with this.

```
function ajaxFunction(str) {
  if (str.length==0) { 
    document.getElementById("search").innerHTML="";
    document.getElementById("search").style.border="0px";
    return;
  }
  var input=document.getElementById('text1').value;
  var ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
  ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (ajaxRequest.readyState==4 && ajaxRequest.status==200) {
        var res=ajaxRequest.responseXML;
        var states=res.getElementsByTagName("states");
        var elem=states[0];
        var items=res.getElementsByTagName("item");
        document.getElementById("search").innerHTML="";
    for(var i=0;i<items.length;i++){

        var item=items[i].getElementsByTagName("label");
        var state=item[0].innerHTML;
        var len=str.length;
        var match=state.substr(0,len);
        if(match.toUpperCase()==input.toUpperCase()){
            var val=items[i].getElementsByTagName("value");
            var value=val[0].innerHTML;
            var e = document.createElement('span');
            e.innerHTML = state+"("+value+")&nbsp;&nbsp;";
            document.getElementById("search").appendChild(e.firstChild);
        }
     }

      document.getElementById("search").style.border="1px solid #A5ACB2";
    }
  }
  ajaxRequest.open("GET","USA_States.xml",true);
  ajaxRequest.send();
}
```